# Illustrator – Automated Line Extensions

Tags: adobe-illustrator, actions

I'm working on creating an action with line extensions in a project, where I need to extend both ends of a line by a predetermined length. However, I'm encountering an issue where recording the action while extending the line does not produce the desired result.

Here's the step-by-step process I'm following:

1. Select the line segment I want to extend.
2. Select one end anchor.
3. Move the anchor a predetermined length for the extension (following the pink line extension).
4. Repeat the process for the other end of the line.

During the recording of the action, I expect the extended line segments to be captured, allowing me to apply the action to other lines later. However, when I play back the recorded action, the line does not extend at all.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue while creating line extensions in an action? Is there a workaround or a specific setting I might be missing? Is there any way to speed up this process, as I will need to extend hundreds of lines in this and future projects. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can not record this. Theres no such feature in recording, only absolute in paper coordinates or percentage based movement/scaling is available. You could script this though

Comment: Although youy can frequently just use transform each to extend lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *action* automation, one needs to *think* about automation. A great deal of manual editing can't be recorded because it would be too complex for actions. (Note *scripting* is a bit different and offers more.)

It is *not* possible to record an *action* which merely selects an anchor and moves it based upon dragging. In fact, it's not possible to record *anything* being moved merely by the user dragging an object. Nothing will record.

What *will* work is using dialogs...

So....

- Select anchor
- Start recording
- Choose `Object > Transform > Move...` and enter the desired distance to move 
  <sup>(and angle, etc.)</sup>
- Stop recording

Now you just need to select an anchor and run the action, it'll then move the same distance in the same direction. And the action **will** work if multiple anchors are selected. Basically, it just records "move selection by x distance".

---

If the distance to move is **different each time**, you may be out of luck, or need scripting. Illustrator actions can *not* do anything such as "Move anchor to *here*." You need to know the actual distance to move (or scale percentage). Actions don't have any sort of "collision detection". In fact Illustrator, as a whole, has very rudimentary collision detection and only related to guides.

One option *may be* if you want all paths to be the ***same* length**. You *can* record an action that unifies all path lengths based on a fixed origin. So you *could* make all selected paths 300pts long *without* moving the left anchor point - something along those lines.